# will_paginate - other queries not showing on page 2 and beyond

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view that shows two Active Record queries, one of which I use will_paginate on.

All works great with will_paginate, but if I click next or page 2, the second query is not longer rendered on the view.

I probably don't understand the flow of will_paginate processing, so any help is appreciated. In particular, why is will_paginate affecting the other, unrelated query from showing in the view?  If I click on the first page, the 2nd query shows up again in the view. The controller returns the two queries and has the .paginate on the one query.

Thanks!

Per request, here's a summary of the code I'm asking about.  I forgot to mention the other query also uses will_paginate.  And therefore, I found my problem.  I was using the same page parameter for both paginates!  I found a good article describing what to do:
http://candidcode.com/2009/11/03/paginating-multiple-models-using-will_paginate-on-the-same-page/

And updated my code, and it works.  This is basically, the correct code when you want two will_paginates on different models on the same view.

Controller:

```
def index

@query1 = Post.somescope.paginate(:page => params[:query1_page], :per_page => 50)   

@query2 =  Post.someotherscope.paginate(:page => params[:query2_page], :per_page => 20)  

end
```

View:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">

<li>
<%= will_paginate @query1, :param_name => 'query1_page' %>
</li>

<% @query1.each do |q1| %>
<li>...</li>
<% end %>

</ul>


<ul class="list-unstyled">

<li>
<%= will_paginate @query2, :param_name => 'query2_page' %>
</li>

<% @query2.each do |q2| %>
<li>...</li>
<% end %>

</ul>
```

Comment: Could you show us some excerpt of your controller and views?

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: Thanks you two (arnep, OfficeYA) for making me think!

Comment: So your code works now!