# php paginate not showing on page 2

Tags: php, mysqli

I searched for similar question and answers on here and only found one but was not confirmed how issue was fixed ([will_paginate - other queries not showing on page 2 and beyond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761156/will-paginate-other-queries-not-showing-on-page-2-and-beyond))

Basically I had a go at paginate with a test page using a search box and then echo out only one result on each page. Its works on first page but then shows nothing on page 2 on so on.

Can anyone advise if I am missing something silly or missing the point? On my page its just a text box and search and then I wanted it to paginate if more than one result.

Heres the full code

```html
<?php

 require ("cw/connect.php");
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['search']);
    $search = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]i#","", $search);
 $start=0;
 $limit=2;
    //Check Form is not blank
 if (empty($search)){
       $msg = "Please enter a search criteria";
 }
 else {
  

    $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT id, username, first, last, email, about FROM users WHERE 
 first LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR 
 last LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR 
 email LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR 
 about LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR 
 username LIKE '%".$search."%' LIMIT $start, $limit") or die ("There was no search results!");

 $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
 
 if(isset($_GET['id']))
 {
  $id=$_GET['id'];
  $start=($id-1)*$limit;
 }
 else
 {
  $id=1;
 }
 $page=ceil($count/$limit);
    $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT id, username, first, last, email, about FROM users WHERE 
 first LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR 
 last LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR 
 email LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR 
 about LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR 
 username LIKE '%".$search."%' LIMIT $start, $limit") or die ("There was no search results!");
  
  
    if($count == 0){
      $msg = "There was no search results!";

    }else{

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    
        $id = $row ['id'];
        $username = $row ['username'];
        $first = $row ['first'];
        $last = $row ['last'];
        $email = $row ['email'];
        $about = $row ['about'];
  
  //The layout and what will be shown on page
        $msg .='<p><b>ID:</b> '.$id.
  '<br><b>User:</b> '.$username.
  '<br><b>First Name:</b> '.$first.
  '<br><b>Last Name:</b> '.$last.
  '<br><b>Email:</b> '.$email.
  '<br><b>About:</b> '.$about.
  '</p>
  <hr>';

      }
   ?>
   
   <ul>
   
   <?php
   if($id > 1) {
   ?>
   
   <li><a href="?id=<?php echo ($id-1);?>">Previous</a></li>
   <?php } ?>
   
   
   <?php
   for($i=1;$i <= $page; $i++)
   {
   ?>
   
  <li><a href="?id=<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li> 
     
  <?php  
   }
   ?>
   
   <?php
   if($id!=$page)
   {
    
   ?>
   
   <li><a href="?id=<?php echo ($id+1);?>">Next</a></li>
   
   </ul> 
   
 <?php
    }
  }
  }
 }
  ?>
<form action ="" method = "post">
<input name="search" type="text" size="30" placeholder="eg name"/>
<input type="submit" value="search"/> <?php echo "$msg";?>
</form> 

</p>
<br/><br/>
```

Comment: Why are you including `cw/connect.php` twice?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake when I was copying over, I have removed it now

Comment: Why are you first fetching all matching records and then fetch _all_ records (without the conditions) with a limit and offset? You should also check what your second query actually looks like.

Comment: Hi, I have tried with the same query for both but still end up with the same result of contents on the first page but no contents on the 2nd and so on(with the $start and $limit above the first query)

Comment: When you click on "next", you have lost the search text. Change your search form to use GET instead (and fetch it with `$_GET['search']`) and then add that text to your link: `href="?id=<?php echo $i;?>&search=<?= $search ?>"`.

Comment: I changed the search form to GET and included the $_GET['search'] along with the link href="?id=<?php echo $i;?>&search=<?= $search ?> and results this time where blank

Comment: Did you change all your `$_POST['search']` to `$_GET['search']`? the `isset()` and in your `mysqli_real_escape_string()`?

Comment: I can only assume this is not working as its a search form(posting data) instead of get once query is run?

Comment: POST vs GET doesn't matter for the form as long as you get the correct param ($_POST vs $_GET) in your code. You can't have the form as POST since you won't be able to pass the search text along to the next and previous pages when you click the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have restructured the code quite a bit.

1. I've removed the second query, because the count you do isn't required in that position and can be moved down. Therefore removing a query.
2. I've updated your button links with a forward slash, so it doesnt append ? everytime (?id=1?id=1?id=1 after 3 clicks)
3. Made the HTML pagination better to read using the built-in php templating system
4. **The biggest one** - you lose your search query after you click on the link, so i have transformed the form to GET and added the parameters to the link of the previous and next pages.

So my result is this - beware - I havent tested it:

```
require("cw/connect.php");
$msg = "";
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_GET['search']);
    $search = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]i#","", $search);

    if (empty($search)) {
        $msg = "Please enter a search criteria";
    } else {
        $items_per_page = 1;
        $page_id = 1;
        $start = 0;

        // added a little validation
        if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 1) {
            $page_id    = $_GET['id'];
            $start = ceil($page_id * $items_per_page);
        }

        $query = "SELECT id, username, first, last, email, about FROM users WHERE 
            first LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
            last LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
            email LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
            about LIKE '%".$search."%' OR 
            username LIKE '%".$search."%'";

        $result_query = mysqli_query($connect, $query . "LIMIT ".$start.",".$items_per_page) or die ("There are no search results!");
        $count_query = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die("There are no search results");

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($count_query);
        $page  = ceil($count / $items_per_page);

        if ($count <= 0) {
            $msg = "There where no search results!";
        } else {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_query)) {
                $user_id       = $row ['id'];
                $username = $row ['username'];
                $first    = $row ['first'];
                $last     = $row ['last'];
                $email    = $row ['email'];
                $about    = $row ['about'];

                //The layout and what will be shown on page
                $msg .= '<p><b>ID:</b> '.$user_id.
                    '<br><b>User:</b> '.$username.
                    '<br><b>First Name:</b> '.$first.
                    '<br><b>Last Name:</b> '.$last.
                    '<br><b>Email:</b> '.$email.
                    '<br><b>About:</b> '.$about.
                    '</p><hr>';
            } ?>
            <ul>
                <?php if ($page_id > 1): ?>
                    <li><a href="/?id=<?php echo($page_id - 1); ?>&search=<?php echo $search; ?>">Previous</a></li>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $page; $i++): ?>
                    <li><a href="/?id=<?php echo $i; ?>&search=<?php echo $search; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
                <?php endfor; ?>

                <?php if ($page_id != $page): ?>
                    <li><a href="/?id=<?php echo($page_id + 1); ?>&search=<?php echo $search; ?>">Next</a></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
    <?php }
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="get">
    <input name="search" type="text" size="30" placeholder="eg name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="search"/>
</form>
<?php echo "$msg"; ?>
```

Comment: Hi sbrn, thank you for that and I appreciate the updates :). on testing this I seem to be getting the same result as previous. The result shows on search  submit as expected, however when it comes to page 2 and so on it goes blank again

Comment: Apologies, its not going blank when I click the next page it changing in the URL but the content is the same as the first page and the pagination is not increasing to the amount of pages that should be displayed. Say 1 result per page. If theres 10 results I should see 10 page links 1,2,3,4 ect.... But now I ways see Previous | 1 | Next

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if you are experiencing any issues.

Comment: Hi sbrn, Thanks for doing that. on running this with the update, I now see the correct number of pages. But this time no results. As its now given the error, Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in C:\wamp64\www\testing\test2.php on line 36. Line 36 is 'while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {'

Comment: Oh whops, i've missed the $query in your while loop. Ill edit the answer

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks so much for your assistance with this. I really appreciate it! Thank sbrn, I added to rep